# Couldn't access magento's guest api via Android

Tags: rest, magento, android-asynctask

Couldn't access magento's guest api via Android sdk.

I was try to access the magento API from mobile application. when I am trying to access from iOS(Using AFNetworking library for API) , working fine.

But the issue with Android, using Asynchtask  (Used Volley and Retrofit) but can't able to access, am getting "**500 Service unavailable error**".

Answer (score 0):

Am fix those issue using "Auth_Token" and add as a post param ,which are given by magento developer. It may help to some other people.